# International characters resulting in bad OAuth 1.0 body hash

Tags: oauth, mastercard

I'm getting a body hash mismatch when the POST body of an XML web service request contains international characters.

From what I've read, it sounds like international characters in a POST body have to be encoded before calculating the OAuth body hash. UTF-8 for CAFÉ of "CAF%c3%89" doesn't seem to work with the MasterCard Match web service. I'm having trouble with the tool we're using (iWay Service Manager) re-interpreting "CAF&#201;" back to "CAFÉ". Before I figure out how to squeeze an encoder in before the OAuth step, I was hoping to confirm with someone who had dealt with this issue.

What is the proper encoding to use on a POST body with international characters (or is my problem likely to be something else)?

Answer (score 0):

For calculating MasterCard OAuth body hash, the recommended encoding is **UTF-8**. Also the Core SDK made available by MasterCard uses **UTF-8** encoder to encode oauth_body_hash.

Answer (score 0):

For Mastercard an error I could encode the utf-8
Core SDK cause I'm the masters beneficiary and they keep messing with my MASTERSCARD from t mobile money card

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).